# How do I change active grease pencil palette color via python?

Tags: python, scripting, grease-pencil

I am making script that makes new gpencil stroke and changes the color of it to colors that already exists in palette.

Problem I'm facing is that `bpy.ops.gpencil.stroke_change_color()` operator only changes color of selected strokes to selected color! And I have no way to select colors in palette by python script.

I don't want to make new colors because I want specific line color, fill color, opacity. Plus, I don't want to make piles of same colors in gpencil palette.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of a specific color in a specific palette using this:

```
bpy.data.grease_pencil["GPencil"].palettes["GP_Palette"].colors["Color"].color = (1, 0, 0)
```